# What is a "modified red zone offense"?

Tags: american-football

What is a modified red zone offense? I know what the [red zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_zone_(gridiron_football)) is, but the announcer said "modified red zone".

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In what context did the announcer mention a "modified red zone"?

Comment: Do you remember what the situation was? It's likely related to something going on during the game like last play of the game, or last minute of the game with no timeouts, etc

Comment: Is it possible that it's about grammar? I mean (I read it that way at first sight) : "modified *red-zone-offense*" where the offense tactic is modified because of the red zone area? And not a modified red zone area for the offensive team?